# SQL Basic Query Help! Sum of Sales on Specific date for Specific Products

Tags: sql, sum

I need to write a quick bit of code and for the life of me can't work out how to do it - it's been so long since I've had to use SQL, and I've had a mind-lapse.

I need to sum the sales for product A, product B and product C - one total for each product, for `November 27th 2015` (in date format `YYYY_MM-DD`).

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The basic idea is this

```
SELECT
ProductName
,SUM(SalesQuantity) Sales
FROM TableName
WHERE SalesDate = '2015_11-27'
    AND ProductName IN ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY ProductName
```

But it all depends on your data structure.

Also, if this is homework then just say. We'd be happy to help you along but doing it for you is not going to help you at all.

Comment: It's not homework, well I hope not at 28! Haha. I'm just a girl trying to progress her data analytics career - I had been trying to self-teach myself SQL in a previous job, and I haven't touched it since 2014 - and now I'm trying to pick it up again. What you've written makes complete sense to me though, so I really appreciate that! Thank you

Comment: Sure, no worries. I've been noticing a lot of homework type requests on here lately, apologies for assuming this is one of them. Giving more information in your original post would be great though. Some idea of your table structure and what you've previously attempted is always a great start.

Comment: If you're looking for learning resources, this is a good place to start https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/wiki/index

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are looking for this.because you want Sum of specific date for specific product.

```
SELECT
   ProductName
  , SUM(A) as jan
  , SUM(B) as feb
  , SUM(C) as mar
  , SUM(A+B+C) as Total
FROM TableName
WHERE SalesDate = '2015_11-27'
GROUP BY ProductName
```